# keytool importing multiple certificates in single file

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

How to import multiple certificates in a single file with keytool [to cert store]?

keytool -importcert only imports the first one.

Comment: what kind of file is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to include the CA certificates you should add the `-trustcacerts` option.

If you have multiple certificate chains in one PEM file you will have to split the file.

Comment: that's not the question - how do I add multiple of them from single file?

Answer (score 40):

A bash script that will import all certificates from a PEM file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PEM_FILE=$1
PASSWORD=$2
KEYSTORE=$3
# number of certs in the PEM file
CERTS=$(grep 'END CERTIFICATE' $PEM_FILE| wc -l)

# For every cert in the PEM file, extract it and import into the JKS keystore
# awk command: step 1, if line is in the desired cert, print the line
#              step 2, increment counter when last line of cert is found
for N in $(seq 0 $(($CERTS - 1))); do
  ALIAS="${PEM_FILE%.*}-$N"
  cat $PEM_FILE |
    awk "n==$N { print }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { n++ }" |
    keytool -noprompt -import -trustcacerts \
            -alias $ALIAS -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass $PASSWORD
done
```

For example:

```
./jks_import_pem TrustedCAs.PEM changeit truststore.jks
```

Comment: I had to add "-storetype JKS" to the keytool line in this script, otherwise I was getting the error:  Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.  After that, everything has worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same thing, but apparently it's only possible if you're importing the key as well:

> There are two types of entries- key entries and trusted cert entries,
>   and only the key entry can contain a "chain" of certificates, attached
>   to it. The trusted cert entries are all single cert entries.

(https://www.java.net/node/674524#comment-709695)

I even tried [converting to PKCS#7 format first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062331/399105), but it didn't work, either because of the above reason or because my version of keytool was too old.

So had to first split the file into separate certs:

```
cat certchain.pem | awk 'split_after==1{n++;split_after=0} /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {split_after=1} {print > ("cert" n ".pem")}'
```

(https://serverfault.com/q/391396/58568)

Then import each one individually.

Comment: Note that to be strictly correct, you'll need parentheses around the string concatenation: `("cert" n ".pem")`. Without them, some versions of awk will get confused (OS X, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the free and easy to use GUI Tool
[Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)
to import and manage multiple certificates.

Comment: That doesnt do multiple certificate import at once

Answer (score 1):

You can use the p11-kit tool that can does this very quicky.
The only constraint is that it reads the certificates from /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/

```
/usr/bin/p11-kit extract --format=java-cacerts --filter=ca-anchors \
                --overwrite --purpose server-auth $DEST/java/cacerts
```

Answer (score 1):

**Importing certs with proper key alias name:**

```
#!/bin/bash
PEM_FILE=$1
PASSWORD=$2
KEYSTORE=$3
# number of certs in the PEM file
CERTS=$(grep 'END CERTIFICATE' $PEM_FILE| wc -l)

# For every cert in the PEM file, extract it and import into the JKS keystore
# awk command: step 1, if line is in the desired cert, print the line
#              step 2, increment counter when last line of cert is found
for N in $(seq 0 $(($CERTS - 1))); do


    rm -f tmp.pem
    cat $PEM_FILE |
    awk "n==$N { print }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { n++ }" > tmp.pem
   

   ALIAS=$(openssl x509 -in tmp.pem -noout -text  | grep Subject: | sed 's/.*CN=//')

   #Optional: adding index to alias name
   ALIAS=$(echo "${N}_${ALIAS}")
    echo $ALIAS

    cat $PEM_FILE |
    awk "n==$N { print }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { n++ }" |
    keytool -noprompt -import -trustcacerts \
           -alias "${ALIAS}" -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass $PASSWORD

done
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly improved the top answer to **retain the alias names**:

```
#!/bin/bash
PEM_FILE=$1
PASSWORD=$2
KEYSTORE=$3
# number of certs in the PEM file
CERTS=$(grep 'END CERTIFICATE' $PEM_FILE| wc -l)

# For every cert in the PEM file, extract it and import into the JKS keystore
# awk command: step 1, if line is in the desired cert, print the line
#              step 2, increment counter when last line of cert is found
for N in $(seq 0 $(($CERTS - 1))); do
  ALIAS=`cat $PEM_FILE |  awk "n==$N { print }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { n++ }" | grep '#' | cut -c3-`
  # echo "$ALIAS"
  cat $PEM_FILE |
    awk "n==$N { print }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { n++ }" |
    keytool -noprompt -import -trustcacerts \
            -alias "$ALIAS" -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass $PASSWORD
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import multiple CA certificates within one pem file. Ensure the root CA is first, followed by the rest.

Answer (score -1):

The given answers are not really Ansible solutions, more like alternatives.

What i wrote below works for the 1st certificate, but it's not looping. Any ideas?

```
    java_install_keystore_cert: true
    java_keystore_certs: "{{ apps.jira.keystore_certs }}"
    java_keystore_cert_alias: test
```

```
apps:
  jira:
    keystore_certs:
      - certName: xyz.xxx.com
        certFileName: xyz.xxx.com.pem
      - certName: xxx.com
        certFileName: xxx.com.pem
```

```
- name: Copy SSL certificate to remote server
  copy:
    src: "{{ java_keystore_certs[0].certFileName }}"
    #src: "{{ java_keystore_cert_file }}"
    dest: /tmp/
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false)

- name: Determine Java cacerts keystore location
  find:
    paths: "{{ java_home }}/"
    patterns: 'cacerts'
    recurse: yes
  register: cacerts_file
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false)

- name: Import SSL certificate to Java cacerts keystore
  java_cert:
    cert_alias: "{{ java_keystore_cert_alias }}"
    #cert_path: "/tmp/{{ java_keystore_cert_file }}"
    cert_path: "/tmp/{{ java_keystore_certs[0].certFileName }}"
    keystore_path: "{{ cacerts_file.files[0].path }}"
    keystore_pass: changeit
    executable: "{{ java_home }}/bin/keytool"
    state: present
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false) and cacerts_file is defined
```

Answer (score -1):

I also switched to a not-just Ansible solution....

```
  copy:
    src: "{{ java_keystore_cert_file }}"
    dest: /tmp/
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false)

- name: Determine Java keystore (cacerts) location
  find:
    paths: "{{ java_home }}/"
    patterns: 'cacerts'
    recurse: yes
  register: cacerts_file
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false)

# Not using the java_cert module (anymore) since that imports the first certificate only

# Always use .pem (simply rename .crt or .cert to .pem if needed)
# The .pem file should contain one or more public certificates, no private key(s) or chain
- name: Transfer the import certificate script
  copy:
    src: files/scripts/importcert.sh
    dest: /tmp/importcert.sh
    mode: 0700
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false) and cacerts_file is defined

- name: Import certificate to Java keystore
  command: sh /tmp/importcert.sh "/tmp/{{ java_keystore_cert_file }}" "{{ java_home }}/bin/keytool" changeit "{{ cacerts_file.files[0].path }}"
  when: java_install_keystore_cert|default(false) and cacerts_file is defined
```

```
#!/bin/bash
PEM_FILE=$1
KEYTOOL=$2
PASSWORD=$3
KEYSTORE=$4
# number of certs in the PEM file
CERTS=$(grep 'END CERTIFICATE' $PEM_FILE| wc -l)

# For every cert in the PEM file, extract it and import into the JKS keystore
# awk command: step 1, if line is in the desired cert, print the line
#              step 2, increment counter when last line of cert is found
for N in $(seq 0 $(($CERTS - 1))); do
  ALIAS="${PEM_FILE%.*}-$N"
  cat $PEM_FILE |
    awk "n==$N { print }; /END CERTIFICATE/ { n++ }" |
    $KEYTOOL -noprompt -import -trustcacerts \
            -alias $ALIAS -keystore $KEYSTORE -storepass $PASSWORD
done
```