# Unable to connect to LDAP server over ssl using spring template

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ssl, ldap

I  am using spring template to connect to ldap server over ssl. I used the following command to save ssl certificate from server:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect <ldapserverip>:<port> | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ldapserver.pem
```

Then went to /jre/lib/security directory and executed the following command to add certificate to cacerts.

```
keytool -import -keystore cacerts -file ldapserver.pem
```

Then verified the count in list of entries in cacerts using the command:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts
```

I am running the application in tomcat and tomcat is pointed to same JDK_HOME.

I am getting the following exception in tomcat while logging in using authenticate() in ldapTemplate using spring.

```
Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It was working fine with plain text (with out https). I tried setting VMArguments as well but none of them worked.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="<path to cacerts file>"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="<passphrase>"
```

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: If you use the `-showcerts` option with openssl you can see all the certificates in the chain up to the issuing CA. All intermediate certificates need to be imported as well.

Comment: Thanks mvreijn, how to get all the certificates in the chain upto issuing CA. I tried -showcerts option but it says invalid option for openssl.

Comment: -showcerts is working fine but its not showing all the certificates and in the last line i am getting "Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)". Is there any command to get entire certificate chain so that i can direct import them into my cacerts?

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a few days - good to see that you have solved the issue.

Comment: Thats ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain of trust is broken it looks like. Two possible reasons.

1. The certificate from server is not a single certificate but a chain up to root CA and you have imported only one. You need to verify and import that complete chain.

   a. To check the certificate chain, dump it using openssl

   ```
   >openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:port
   ```

   b. To import the chain you need either convert PEM to PKCS#7 or split.

   i. [Convert PEM to PKCS#7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062072/how-to-add-certificate-chain-to-keystore)

   ii. [Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660767/keytool-importing-multiple-certificates-in-single-file)
2. While importing the certificate use "-trustcacerts" option so that certificates from keystore are considered for chain of trust.

   ```
   >keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /path/ldapserver.pem -alias somealias -keystore /security/cacerts
   ```

Comment: Thanks Roshith, how to get complete chain up to root CA . Is there any command to get complete chain

Comment: Thanks Roshith, I got actual certificate with complete chain and got the issue solved.

Comment: @user1188867 Happy to help.