# Azure Graph API: Unable to find valid certification path to requested target on REST call

Tags: rest, ssl, azure-ad-graph-api, oim

I'm working on an integration from Oracle Identity Manager with Office 365 for license provisioning (main purpose). When I get to the point where the Connector tries to call de REST service for a token request, it fails with the following error:

> SEVERE: org.identityconnectors.restcommon.ClientHandler : executeRequest : Error occurred while executing a POST REST call on the target. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I already downloaded the cert path from my browser on the url specified for this call and imported it to my java keystore but still getting this error.

Does anybody know if something specific is required on the Microsoft side for this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608953/unable-to-connect-to-ldap-server-over-ssl-using-spring-template/39610306#39610306

Comment: @Miguel Ángel Are you using Generic REST connector?

Comment: @varpekv it's an official connector for Office 365, but basically yeah. It's all built over the Generic REST Connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out the answers was simpler than what I thought. I was missing the part of importing the certificates to the Trust keystore (I was just importing them on the cacerts jdk file). I did that and worked just fine.

Thanks all.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue as yours. Please what do you mean by "importing the certificates to the Trust keystore " ? where is the Trust keystore? and how you did it please?