# Getting "Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors" error when trying to connect to AWS RDS MySQL instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

I am trying to write a Java application (using Java 17) that connects to an AWS RDS MySQL instance using IAM authentication. Amazon has a [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html) describing how to do this, along with a complete [Java example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.AuthToken.Connect).

The Java example uses SSL to connect, so I tried the following certificate bundles listed on the Amazon [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) that describes using SSL to connect to RDS:

- [global-bundle.pem](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem)
- [us-west-2-bundle.pem](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/us-west-2/us-west-2-bundle.pem) (because our RDS instance is located in us-west-2)
- [rds-ca-2019-us-west-2.pem](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-us-west-2.pem) - used in the example code, but is not listed in the above SSL document for some reason

Here is the example code in simplified form:

```
    X509Certificate x509Cert;
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    URL url = new File("c:\\users\\me\\documents\\global-bundle.pem").toURI().toURL();
    try (InputStream certInputStream = url.openStream()) {
        x509Cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
    }

    File keyStoreFile = File.createTempFile("sys-connect-via-ssl-test-cacerts", ".jks");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyStoreFile.getPath())) {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS", "SUN");
        ks.load(null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("rootCaCertificate", x509Cert);
        ks.store(fos, "changeit".toCharArray());
    }

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStoreFile.getPath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);

    RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator generator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
            .credentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).region("us-west-2").build();
    String authToken = generator.getAuthToken(GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
            .hostname(RDS_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME).port(3306).userName(DB_USER).build());

    Properties mysqlConnectionProperties = new Properties();
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("verifyServerCertificate","true");
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("useSSL", "true");
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("user",DB_USER);
    mysqlConnectionProperties.setProperty("password",authToken);

    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + RDS_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME + ":3306", mysqlConnectionProperties);
```

The code fails on the call to `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` with the following exception:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at IAMDatabaseAuthenticationTester.run(IAMDatabaseAuthenticationTester.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:759)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[...]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

The same exception happens if I replace `global-bundle.pem` with `us-west-2-bundle.pem` or `rds-ca-2019-us-west-2.pem`.

I looked up the "Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors" error and saw tons of questions on StackOverflow - most of them do not have answers. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286407/ssl-exception-on-java-path-does-not-chain-with-any-of-the-trust-anchors) of the few with answers says that you need both the root certificate as well as the intermediate certificate for your region. But according to the Amazon SSL [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), the `global-bundle.pem` and `us-west-2-bundle.pem` files contain both the root certificates and the intermediate certificates for the AWS region(s). I also loaded the `global-bundle.pem` and `us-west-2-bundle.pem` files in [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/), and confirmed that they have both root CAs and non-root CAs, so I don't think that is the problem.

Any idea why the code is not working? It almost seems like Amazon did not test their code at all.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation after applying an upgrade on AWS RDS instance for CA Certificates. It looked like somehow, application was not able to connect and it seemed RDS didn't exist on the same RDS endpoint.

[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] 2023-10-11 05:46:49.750 DEBUG 2052 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

but after a careful look I found the actual cause to be a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException as shown below:

[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:361) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011... 191 common frames omitted
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:347) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:186) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:456) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:427) ~[na:na]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:315) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] #011at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:352) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]

Im my case, the log also showed another problem:
com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: null,  message from server: "Host '10.0.0.111' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

The solution to both of my problems was thus the usual fix of appending &useSSL=false at the end of the [JDBC URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database) and also restarting my RDS instance.

I am pretty sure that you went through the same problem.
Always pay attention to String "Caused by:". The problems my log showed me were multiple such as:

1- [2023-10-11 04:44:43] [info] 2023-10-11 04:44:43.820 DEBUG 1166 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: null,  message from server: "Host '10.0.0.108' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'"

2- [2023-10-11 05:10:18] [warning] javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory]

3- [2023-10-11 05:10:18] [warning] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

4-[2023-10-11 05:10:37] [info] 2023-10-11 05:10:37.027 DEBUG 1258 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
[2023-10-11 05:10:37] [info] com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

and it followed by the trace with string "Caused by:" that showed the real problem with my application i.e.

[2023-10-11 05:46:49] [info] Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure