# ePassport Passive Authentication in Android(java) using jmrtd

Tags: android, authentication, certificate, x509certificate, ca

I am performing Passive Authentication of passport chip using jmrtd.
I am able to verify signature using DSC(Digital Singing Certificate).
But I am not able to verify DSC using CSC (Country Signing Certificate).

Please provide some approach, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have info/reference on how you initiated passive authentication using JMRTD?

Answer (score 1):

Probably way too late for you, but in case anyone else runs in to this :)

To do that you basically need to create a trust store with the CSCs. Basically they are just certificate authorities and needs to be treated as such.

First step is to create a PKCS12 containing all the CSCs you want/need, this for some reason can't be done using OpenSSL, but fortunately keytool is your friend: [keytool importing multiple certificates in single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660767/keytool-importing-multiple-certificates-in-single-file)

Next up is creating a trust store, e.g., by following this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379434/1441857

The keystore needed for the step above is created as follows:

```java
private KeyStore createStore(InputStream pkcs12Stream) {
    final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keyStore.load(pkcs12Stream, "password".toCharArray());
    return keyStore;
}
```

finally you can simply validate by using your trustmanager(s) (there's actually just one, as expected), following the first answer I linked.  The `authType` parameter seems to be `"RSA_EXPORT"`, haven't figured why yet.

I think that should do the trick :)